# Can someone explain me the iphone certificate stuff, how the steps look like?

Tags: iphone, certificate, store

can someone explain me the iphone certificate stuff, how the steps look like?

Im really confused...

Regards,
Mirza

Comment: Could you give more details? What stage are you at? Have you created your developer certificates? Tell us more.

Comment: Have you read the explaining webpage at apple's?

Comment: Apple explains them pretty well in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Complete steps are given for deployment of an app on iPhone device using certificates.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

REFER [IOS development guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/iOS_Development_Guide.pdf)

refer chapter-3 in this guide.